# Create Toast by a static method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I use this code in all my  app fragments and it should be better if I use a static method. How can I do it? This static method should also works on fragment, not only activities.

My not static showToast method:

```
public void showToast(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

SOLVED BY USING THIS STATIC METHOD thanks @KishanDhamat

```
public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {
Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}

Comment: Well what activity would you expect `getActivity()` to return if you're calling this from a static method? (Also note that following Java naming conventions, this should be `showToast`.)

Comment: But that method it is not static, I call it every time in my fragments. By the way I have edited the main question

Comment: see my edits for answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {
    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

now for calling this method you should call like this:

```
ClassName.showToast(context,"text");
```

Here classname is class that containing  static method.

Answer (score 3):

- Change the signature of the method and add given `Context` as parameter
- Change the signature of the method to make it `static`
- Pass the `Context` as first argument of your `Toast.makeText` call

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void changeActivity(Context context,Class that){
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, that));
} // my static method

  public void forgotPass(View view){
    Function.changeActivity(LoginActivity.this,ForgotPass.class);
} // my activity i want to change
```

This is my solution, hope it can help